# How to use the new input system in unity for attacking?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am making a game in unity and attempting to have working attacks with a different animation for each of the directions (up, down, left and right). At the moment, I am only trying to get the animations working but I do not know how to change an animator Boolean variable based on input from the user, in this case the OnFire message. I have found tutorials that say how to do this for a single attacking direction, and others for doing this by flipping the attack animation, however I would like to use all 4 of my animations for direction of attack.

I will include my current script below, if anyone is able to help that would be great. (This is a bad description so any questions people have I will answer)

```cs
private void FixedUpdate() //This function is called a fixed number of times each second
{
    //This is all script for the movement and animation of the player
    if(movementInput != Vector2.zero)
    {
        bool success = TryMove(movementInput);
        //If it is not possible to move in both directions at the same time
        if (!success)
        {
            success = TryMove(new Vector2(movementInput.x, 0)); //Try to move in the x direction

            if (success)
            {
                success = TryMove(new Vector2(0, movementInput.y)); //Try to move in the y direction
            }
        }
        if(movementInput.x < 0) //If the player is moving left
        {
            animator.SetBool("IsMovingLeft", true); //The Boolean variable for moving left is the only thing set to true
            animator.SetBool("IsMovingDown", false);
            animator.SetBool("IsMovingRight", false);
            animator.SetBool("IsMovingUp", false);
        }
        else if(movementInput.x > 0) //If the player is moving right
        {
            animator.SetBool("IsMovingLeft", false);
            animator.SetBool("IsMovingDown", false);
            animator.SetBool("IsMovingRight", true); //The Boolean variable for moving right is the only thing set to true
            animator.SetBool("IsMovingUp", false);
        }
        else if(movementInput.y < 0) //If the player is moving down
        {
            animator.SetBool("IsMovingLeft", false);
            animator.SetBool("IsMovingDown", true); //The Boolean variable for moving down is the only thing set to true
            animator.SetBool("IsMovingRight", false);
            animator.SetBool("IsMovingUp", false);
        }
        else if(movementInput.y > 0) //If the player is moving up
        {
            animator.SetBool("IsMovingLeft", false);
            animator.SetBool("IsMovingDown", false);
            animator.SetBool("IsMovingRight", false);
            animator.SetBool("IsMovingUp", true); //The Boolean variable for moving up is the only thing set to true
        }
    }
}

void TakeDamage(int damage)
{
    currentHealth -= damage;
}

private bool TryMove(Vector2 direction)
{
    //Check for potential collisions
    int count = rb.Cast(
        direction, //X and Y values between -1 and 1 that represent the direction from the body to look for collisions
        movementFilter, //The settings that determine where a collision can occur on, such as layers to collide with
        castCollisions, //List of collisions to store the found collisions into after the cast is finished
        moveSpeed * Time.fixedDeltaTime + collisionOffset);

    if (count == 0)
    {
        rb.MovePosition(rb.position + direction * moveSpeed * Time.fixedDeltaTime); //Moving the game object
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

void OnMove(InputValue movementValue)
{
    movementInput = movementValue.Get<Vector2>();
}

void OnFire(InputValue )
{
    //Difficulty is here (I think)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem, it turns out my problem was using a Boolean variable to transition between states when it was easier to use a trigger as a condition. So my final code for starting the attack animation looked like this:
[Attack animation script image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fIIch.png)